# writing to a new empty file using applescript

Tags: applescript

I have a very peculiar file system I want to automate using Applescript. The script I'm using works for the most part, but there is one small step I can't seem to tune down properly. The script should operate like this; when it is run, the script asks the user to choose a folder. Once selected, the script locates all files within the folder with the a specific extension (in this case jpg) Next, the script creates a blank text document for each jpg file using the picture files name as the new name. Once complete, the new text document should have text inputted from a separate pre stated file.

For example, I run the file and pick a folder with 3 images (cake1.jpg, pie2.jpg, icecream3.jpg) The script creates 3 text documents (cake1.txt, pie2.txt, icecream3.txt) but then needs to copy the text from Script2Text.rtf into each of the new documents created. Here is the portion of the script I have that works and what I'm trying to work with

```
set aFolder to choose folder "Select folder to be processed"
set extensionText to text of "txt"

set theDocument to ((path to desktop as Unicode text) & "Script2Text.rtf")
set pasteText to (read file theDocument from 1)

set astid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "{"
set pasteText to text from text item 2 to -1 of pasteText


set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\\marg"
set part1 to text item 1 of pasteText
set part2 to text from text item 2 to -1 of pasteText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to astid
set RTFreturn to "\\" & return
set pasteText to RTFreturn & RTFreturn & part1 & text from paragraph 2 to -1 of part2

tell application "Finder"
    set allFiles to every file of entire contents of aFolder whose name extension is in {"jpg"}
    repeat with x in allFiles
        set FileName to name of x
        if FileName contains ".jpg" then
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "jpg"
            if the (count of text items of FileName) is 2 then
                set NewName to (((first text item of FileName) as string) & extensionText & ((last text item of FileName) as string)) as text
                tell application "Finder" to make file at aFolder with properties {name:NewName}

            else
                display dialog ("Text appears more than once. No changes made to " & FileName)
            end if
        end if

    end repeat
end tell
```

I can't seem to get the rest of this code to sync and add the text into the file. I know the code for ADDING works if I specify a target file directly, (like where I specify the set theDocument, if I set a second file, then set doc2access to that file, I can write to it no problem) but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to specify the file from the automated creation step, which would help.

Here is the code I found that works in writing to a file. I just need to specify it to write to the files being created.

```
set doc2access to (open for access file doc2 with write permission)
    try
        set z to -1
        repeat until ((read doc2access from z for 1) is "}")
            set z to z - 1
        end repeat
        write pasteText to doc2access starting at z
        on error msg
            display dialog msg buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon stop
end try
close access doc2access
```

What I want to do is take the document NewName (which is the variable for the file being created during this portion of the script) and add the text to it. Like if it makes the text files for cake1.txt, instead of writing code to put the text directly into cake1.txt, I want the file to be created WITH the text.

UPDATE
I was able to fix my issue by replacing

```
tell application "Finder" to make file at aFolder with properties {name:NewName}
```

with

```
tell application "Finder" to write pasteText to ((make file at aFolder with properties {name:NewName}) as alias)
```

Comment: Do you really want to do this with Applescript? It is very verbose and clumsy and only works on macOS computers. Just my 2 cents, but I think you would be FAR better off using `bash` which runs on macOS, all Linux/Unix computers and evens Windows 10 (apparently). You would find far more folks who could help you too. Anyway, how about showing sample contents of `Script2Text.rtf`please? And how the result will look for one image file.

Comment: Im using Applescript because thats what is available to me and I've been using it to do things on this mac for a while. Text in Script2Text is irrelevant as I can copy the text just fine; its finding how to get the files I'm making to receive the copied text. My example with cake, pie and ice-cream was an oversimplification. I actually have several hundred files with varying coded names (such as A8221, A8222, HS179, etc) that I just need to make text files with the copied text. I just need to find a way to copy the text to each file when said files are created.

Comment: The text is not irrelevant - unless all files get the entire content of the Script2Text written to them. Do they?

Comment: the files do get the entire content of Script2Text. I did just now resolve the issue I was having though, and will amend my original post with the correct code shortly. Thank you for helping me, regardless!

Answer (score 0):

I know you have a solution already, but I just wanted to back up my comment about Applescript being verbose and show you, and anyone looking at trying to do something similar in future, a way of doing this just using `bash` and `Perl` both of which are included on all versions of OS X.

Once you have selected the folder using Applescript, and assuming you want to create a `.txt` file to match each `.jpg` file, you would run something like this using `do shell script`:

```
find someDirectory -iname \*.jpg -exec perl -MFile::Copy -e '($txt=$ARGV[0])=~s/JPG$/txt/i; copy("Text2File",$txt)' {} \;
```

That says... *"Start in `someDirectory` and look for all files in all subdirectories ending in `JPG` (not case sensitive) and for each one run a Perl script. The Perl script takes the JPG filename as parameter and replaces (case insensitively) `JPG` with `txt` and copies the file named `Text2File` (with your text in it) to the text file whose name we just calculated."*

Answer (score -1):

```
set theWords to read file (((path to desktop) as text) & "Script2Text.rtf")
tell application "Finder" to repeat with someName in {"cake1", "pie2", "icecream"}
    try
        write theWords to ((make file with properties {name:someName}) as alias)
    end try
end repeat
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to add this bit; the examples I gave are not indicative to the ACTUAL files being created. cake1, pie2, icecream3 are not actual images I am dealing with, so I cannot use them in the script. I have the method for creating the text files. I only need to take these files when they are created and add the text to them.

Comment: After digging into your code a bit more, I was able to decipher a solution. The solution will be added to the original post shortly